# Memory usage and leaks ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I just used the instrument to monitor how my app performs and below is the result. I only monitored memory leaks and usage. Does the below result look acceptable ? I am new to this whole app development so i would like an expert opinion :)

**NOTE: this is done on the ios simulator**

thank you

[image: Test Result]

Comment: 43 seconds of trace is not enough usually..

Comment: Also run the Analyzer on your code.  The Leaks tool will not catch all lost memory allocations, heap shots will help with that, here is a great tutorial: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you posted means there are no leaks. However, the presence of virtual memory is alarming, you are using too much memory if it resorts to VM.

Comment: This was tested on the Iphone simulator ..when i checked the log for memory monitor.. there were programs like Firefox and all that listed there.. :\ i ran the test for another 2 mins and no sign of memory leaks but the rest stayed the same !

Comment: VM looks normal for the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

First it's show that you don't have any leaks in your program but pay attention to your VM graphic, who is anormaly high

Comment: VM looks normal for the simulator.

Comment: Are these test done in the ios Simulator, or on a real material ?

Comment: ios simulator ! i should have mentioned that in the post. edited it.